# devise + omniauth auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

after i added an application in twitter when i request for an authentication in twitter (/auth/twitter) i get these error message

http://localhost:3000/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/auth/failure"
```

how can i add a valid credential or is there any ssl certificate that must be included in requesting for twitter auth??

my facebook authentication just works fine after i added a parameter ssl certificate that looks like this

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :facebook,'xxx', 'xx', { :scope => 'publish_stream,offline_access,email',:client_options => { :ssl =>{ :ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs" } }}

      provider :twitter, 'xx','xxx' #,{ :client_options => { :ssl =>{ :ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs" } }}
end
```

Comment: recheck your api keys from twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've same problem with you, it happen because oauth_token in twitter login only valid on once request. May be your application trying to refresh when authentication to twitter.

when i've problem like you, my apps trying to refresh the webpage with

```
window.opener.location = "#{request.fullpath}";
```

Until now i'couldn't find how to popup a window when login using twitter. I'm using omniauth and rails 3.0.3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need

site url `http://localhost:3000/`